# How to find a node in a tree in angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion

I have an object that is a tree

```
var data = [
{
 id: 'topNode',
 parameter: 'parameter',
 children: [
   {
       id: 'node1',
       parameter: 'parameter',
       children: [
       {
           id: 'randomNode_1',
           parameter: 'parameter'
       }],
   {   
       id: 'node2',
       parameter: 'parameter'
       children: [
           {
               id: 'randomNode_2',
               parameter: 'parameter'

           },
           {
               id: 'randomNode_3',
               parameter: 'parameter'

           }
       ]
   }
  ]
 }];
```

How can I go about searching the tree for a particualy node and then return that node ?

I wrote a method :

```
    findProposedValueById(idToFind: string, rootNode: TreeNode): TreeNode {
        if (rootNode.getId() === idToFind) {
               return rootNode;
        } else {
              for (const child of rootNode.getChildren()) {
                   this.findProposedValueById(idToFind, child);
              }
        }
   }
```

I call thid method:

```
const draggedProposedValue: TreeNode = 
     this.findProposedValueById(event.currentTarget.id, this.proposedValues )
```

But findProposedValueById method returns always undefined

however, I put a breakpoints at 'return rootNode;'

I stop right now at this point and node is good node

EDIT : 
I debugged

- if i put a return on call method

```
      for (const child of rootNode.getChildren()) {
                  return this.findProposedValueById(idToFind, child);
              }
```

In fact ,he scans to the end the first branch(node1) and when he's finished, he does not go to the 2nd (node2)

- if i don't put a return on call method

```
      for (const child of rootNode.getChildren()) {
                  this.findProposedValueById(idToFind, child);
              }
```

when he founds the node , he don't stopped and continue loop

Comment: Do you get right `idToFind` and `rootNode` value in `findProposedValueById` function?

Comment: yes i get right idToFind and rootNode value

Comment: ok,what is `getId()` and `getChildren()` function?

Comment: yes getId() is function which returns the id  and getChildren is a function which returns an array  of children

Answer (score 0):

You should put `return` before recursion call in `for of` block:

```
findProposedValueById(idToFind: string, rootNode: TreeNode): TreeNode {
        if (rootNode.getId() === idToFind) {
               return rootNode;
        } else {
              for (const child of rootNode.getChildren()) {
                   return this.findProposedValueById(idToFind, child);
              }
        }
   }
```

Comment: that's what I thought too but after adding the return , I always undefined

Comment: So there might be 2 more things:
1) you don't have getId() and getChildren() methods or 2) you really are looking for a node which is not existing in passed root node